# Why doesn't 'post__not_in' work with 'cat'?

Tags: taxonomy

When I write `'cat' => '45'`, then `post__not_in` does not work, if you remove `cat`, then everything works without problems. I would be grateful for your help

```
$args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => 20,
       'post__not_in' => array(7403,7404,7405),
       'cat' => '45',
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key' => 'главный_кр',
        'value' => 'да'
    )
));

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Are you sure there are posts in the category that meet `meta_query`? Try to add to arguments `'fields' => 'ids'` and displaying the results: 1) for `$args` without `'meta_query'`, 2) for `$args` without `'cat'`.

Comment: Уже нашел проблему, спасибо